# Oracle VirtualBox on Windows 10 messing with system sleep

Tags: windows-10, laptop, virtualbox, sleep, power-management

One night, I opened Oracle VirtualBox 5.2.16 on a Windows 10 laptop, but did not start any of the Virtual Machines. Then I pressed the sleep button and the screen went black and I too went to sleep.

In the middle of the night, when I woke up, I saw that the laptop was on; I assumed that I had not press the sleep button so I pressed it again and went back to sleep.

Early morning, when I woke up, the laptop was still on and I again pressed the sleep button and a few minutes later, the laptop turned on again.

Now, I logged in to check the event logs.
**I saw that every 3-4 minutes, there is a loop of events like the following:**

```
The system has returned from a low power state. Wake Source: Timer - VBoxSVC.exe  
The system is entering sleep. Sleep Reason: System Idle  
The system has resumed from sleep.  
The bootmgr spent 0 ms waiting for user input.  
The boot type was 0x2.  
The system has returned from a low power state. Wake Source: Timer - VBoxSVC.exe
```

It seems, when I pressed the sleep button, the laptop did go to sleep, but VirtualBox was constantly resuming it back and Windows 10 was constantly putting back to sleep.

**Why is this occurring ?**
If not a bug, VirtualBox must want to run some code every few minutes, or in general, VirtualBOx have some benefit.

**How to disable it ?**
Current work-around would be to close VirtualBox before pressing the sleep button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible cause and solution here:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=92523&p=445503#p445503

SetWaitableTimer is called with last parameter true. The last parameter is whether or not to resume the system. This results exactly in the described behaviour.

https://www.virtualbox.org/browser/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Main/src-server/win/HostDnsServiceWin.cpp#L192
Line 192.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setwaitabletimer